# Regex With Nested Square brackets

Tags: regex

I have such string `('[Test.A[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.B[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.C[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.D[0]]' <> '')`, I want to use regex to get the items below:

- Test.A[0]
- Test.B[0]
- Test.C[0]
- Test.D[0]

I tried like `\[.*?\]`, but it will return with `[Test.EVAPCT[0]`.

Comment: If your text structure is always like the above example then you can use: [`Test\.[A-Z]\[\d\]`](https://regex101.com/r/Ymt0pA/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[[^\][]*]
\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[\d+]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKlKou/1). *Details*:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:\.\w+)*` - zero or more sequences of a `.` and one or more word chars
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` / `\d+` - one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

See a demo below:

```js
const text = "('[Test.A[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.B[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.C[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.D[0]]' <> '')";
const regex = /\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[[^\][]*]/g;
console.log( text.match(regex) );
```

To also cater for cases like `[Test.F]` you may use a regex following a bit different logic:

```
/(?<=\[)\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?:\[[^\][]*])?(?=])/g
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKlKou/2) and the demo below:

```js
const text = "('[Test.A[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.B[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.C[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.D[0]]' <> '') [Test.F]";
const regex = /(?<=\[)\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?:\[[^\][]*])?(?=])/g;
console.log( text.match(regex) );
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=\[)` -  a location right after a `[` char
- `(\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?:\[[^\][]*])?)` - Group 1: one or more word chars, and then zero or more sequences of `.` and one or more word chars, and then an optional occurrence of a `[...]` substring
- `(?=])` - a location right before a `]` char.

Comment: I have an specific scenaio about the input is `[Test.F]`, it will fail

Comment: @Edward You can probably use `\[(\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?:\[[^\][]*])?)]`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKlKou/2). I added the solution with its description to the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to change regex to make it return matches with `Test.F` instead of return groups with `Test.F`

Comment: @Edward Yes, use lookarounds, `(?<=\[)\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?:\[[^\][]*])?(?=])`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKlKou/3).

Answer (score 1):

Using `\[.*?\]` starts the match with `[` and matches till the first occurrence of `]` where `.*?` can also match `[` and therefore matches too much.

You could match the digits between the square brackets to make it a bit more specific:

```
[^\][]+\[\d+\]
```

The pattern matches

- `[^\][]+`  Match any char except the square brackets using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `\[\d+\]` Match 1+ digits between the square brackets

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZM5qF/1)

A bit more broader variant could be matching optional chars other than `[` `]` or a whitspace char before the square bracket.

```
[^\s\][()']*\[[^\s\][]+\]
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^\s\][()']*` Optionally  match chars other than the listed in the character class
- `\[` Match `[`
- `[^\s\][]+` Match 1+ chars other than `[` `]` or a whitespace char
- `\]` Match the closing `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Li58Dy/1)

```js
const str = `('[Test.F]' <>'' OR '[Test.A[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.B[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.C[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.D[0]]' <> '')`;
const regex = /[^\s\][()']*\[[^\s\][]+\]/g;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Matching `Test.F` instead of `[Test.F]` using a capture group:

```
\[([^\][]*(?:\[[^\][]*])?)]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S16Q9N/1)

```js
const str = `('[Test.A[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.B[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.C[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.D[0]]' <> '') [Test.F]`;
const regex = /\[([^\][]*(?:\[[^\][]*])?)]/g;
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

Comment: I have an specific scenaio about the input is `[Test.F]`, it will fail

Comment: @Edward In that case you could use `[^\s\][]*\[[^\s\][]+\]` see https://regex101.com/r/C25ebm/1

Comment: thanks for quick response, but for `('[Test.F]' <>'' OR '[Test.A[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.B[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.C[0]]' <>'' OR '[Test.D[0]]' <> '')`, it will return `''[Test.F]` while `Test.F` is expected

Comment: @Edward You can exclude matching those characters in the character class `[^\s\][()']*\[[^\s\][]+\]` see https://regex101.com/r/Li58Dy/1

Comment: Is it possible to make it return `Test.F` instead of `[Test.F]`

Comment: @Edward Yes, you can use a capture group in that case `\[([^\][]*(?:\[[^\][]*])?)]` see https://regex101.com/r/S16Q9N/1